# Error: Return empty array result when executed stored procedure SQL Server 2016 by Code Igniter

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, codeigniter-3

I have a trouble when using CodeIgniter executed store procedure on SQL Server. 
On Server SQL, I executed that stored and it worked, return result (1row).

Result when executed store:

[image]

But I use CI and it return an empty result.

I try to use a SQL command to server by CI with a same config and it works better. Return result like server. And store not working.

Please help me.

Comment: Rather than pasting screenshots of IDE. Bring your code and output in question description and wrap it with code highlighter OR table blocks.

Answer (score 2):

I had answers for this.

I add one line code below after BEGIN in my stored

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing it like this:

model

```
  public function get_table_data($param){ 
    $query = $this->db->query('exec my_procedure "'.$param['id'].'"');
    return $query->result_array();
  }
```

controller

```
public function table_data()    {
    $data = $this->My_Model->get_table_data(array(
      'id' => trim($this->input->post('my_id'))
    ));
    echo json_encode($data);    
}
```

Should also check first in your database.php whether it is in `odbc` or in `sqlsrv`